# Is $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$ consistently $\omega$-complete?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, constructibility

*This was previously [asked and bountied](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326484/is-zfcv-l-consistently-omega-complete) on MSE:*

For brevity, let $T$ be $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$.

Say that an extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is *$\omega$-complete* iff it has exactly one $\omega$-model up to elementary equivalence. While the $\omega$-incompleteness of $T$ is easily provable in theories only slightly stronger than $T$ itself, I don't immediately see how to do it in $T$ alone. My question is:

> Is the theory $S:=T+$ "$T$ is $\omega$-complete" consistent?

Here are a couple observations:

- If we replace "$\omega$-model" by "well-founded model," the answer is obviously **yes** under standard assumptions. Let $\alpha$ be the second-smallest ordinal such that $L_\alpha\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. Then $L_\alpha$ also satisfies "$\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$ has exactly one well-founded model." Unfortunately, we have no analogous hierarchy of $\omega$-models, so this is a non-starter here.
- As to the specific choice of theory in question, the point is that (something like) $\mathsf{V=L}$ is needed to block an easy proof of a negative answer via forcing. For example, reasoning in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ had an $\omega$-model $\mathcal{M}$ it would have a countable one $\hat{\mathcal{M}}$, and we could force over $\hat{\mathcal{M}}$ to get a non-elementarily-equivalent $\omega$-model $\hat{\mathcal{N}}$. *(Forcing over ill-founded countable models is no harder really than forcing over well-founded ones.)* The key point here is that forcing preserves $\mathsf{ZFC}$. This breaks down of course for $\mathsf{V=L}$ and so this argument is irrelevant here. Given the paucity of techniques we currently have for building models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in the first place, this seems to be a real issue.

Ultimately I suspect that the answer is negative, but the above two points between them rule out all the lines of attack I've been able to think of so far.

---

EDIT: In light of Farmer S's answer below, let me explicitly mention a rule of thumb which I forgot: **when thinking about properties which are not too far from first-order definable, always consider the hyperarithmetic hierarchy!**

For example, for every $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence $\varphi$, if $\varphi$ has a model then it has a model $M$ which is countable in $L$, and moreover the $L$-least (real coding a) model of $\varphi$ is hyperarithmetic relative to (any real coding) $\varphi$. The property "Is an $\omega$-model of $T$" is expressible as a computable $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence, and this drives Farmer S's point that $T^+\in L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$.

Comment: Is an $\omega$-model one where the natural numbers are the standard ones? I tried to find a definition, and could only find: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113639/what-is-an-omega-model

Comment: @PaceNielsen Yup, an $\omega$-model is one where the naturals are standard. In general, in any context where we have a theory $T$ together with a canonical interpretation of some theory of arithmetic into $T$, we say that an $\omega$-model of $T$ is one in which this interpretation yields a structure isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ itself. The usual examples are: second-order (or higher-order) arithmetic together with the "first-order part" interpretation, and set theories together with the "$\omega$" interpretation. ("Categoricity" results can justify the privileging of a specific interpretation.)

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, what you'd like is (under the assumption that $T$ has an $\omega$-model) the construction of a structure (in the language of set theory) that satisfies $T$, it has a unique proper substructure satisfying $T$, and $\omega$ is standard in the structure.  Is that correct? I ask because I'm trying to figure out what "$T$ is $\omega$-complete" would mean as a statement in some language.  I can see how to express it using a language that allows infinite conjunctions, but that goes beyond the language of set theory.

Comment: @PaceNielsen "$T$ is $\omega$-complete" **is already** a statement in the object language: every model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a notion of "$\omega$-model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$," namely "model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ whose $\omega$ is isomorphic to my $\omega$." There's no linguistic or otherwise "meta" issue here. (In particular, note that if $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ is not an $\omega$-model itself then the $\omega$-models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in the sense of $M$ - assuming $M$ thinks there are any at all - will **not** be genuine $\omega$-models.) So the $S$ of the OP **is** a genuine first-order theory.

Comment: *($S$ being the theory above.)* Similarly, each model of (the first-order theory annoyingly called) second-order arithmetic $\mathsf{Z}_2$ has an "internal" notion of "$\omega$-model of second-order arithmetic" and so on, and the same is true for other special classes of models, such as $\beta$-models. See e.g. Part B of Simpson's [reverse math book](https://www.amazon.com/Subsystems-Second-Order-Arithmetic-Perspectives/dp/0521150140) for the development in arithmetic *(there is no difference whatsoever between this and set theory, in terms of the general methods for expressing such notions)*.

Comment: @PaceNielsen If $M$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, it has a version of $\omega$ (denoted "$\omega^M$") **internal** to itself - this is **in no way meta**. Namely, consider what $M$ thinks is the smallest limit ordinal. We can turn this into a thing which $M$ thinks is (and in fact genuinely is, but that's beside the point) a model of $\mathsf{PA}$ (and indeed much more) by equipping it with what $M$ thinks are ordinal addition and multiplication.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I think if my previous comments don't address the issue satisfyingly you should ask a separate MO question (which I'll happily answer btw!) - this comment thread is getting a bit long (which, granted, is more my fault than yours :P).

Comment: I think my misunderstanding came from interpreting "standard $\omega$" differently.  I took it to mean the metamathematical statement that you are looking at a model whose $\omega$ is isomorphic to your metamathematical/preexisting $\mathbb{N}$.  I gather that, instead, it was meant in an internal sense of standard.

Comment: @PaceNielsen It's "level-dependent" - as with anything else there's an internal version and an external version. The internal version being expressible in the object language, questions like "Is $S$ consistent?" make perfect sense - although the relevant objects arising in answers to such questions may interpret the relevant notions nonstandardly.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Using Barwise compactness one can prove an appropriate version of Gödel's second incompleteness for this context to shows that for any r.e. extension $T$ of ZF, if $T$ has an $\omega$-model, then $T$ has an $\omega$-model that satisfies "$T$ has no $\omega$-model", which provides a high level explanation of what's happening in Farmer F.'s recursion-theoretic solution. I will try to the flesh out this as an alternative answer to your question "before long".

Comment: @NoahSchweber You wrote: "It's "level-dependent" - as with anything else there's an internal version and an external version."  There are some external concepts that are not always internalizable (without expanding language, or logic, etc...).  I see now that you define, externally, "standardness" to merely mean an isomorphism from the metatheoretical thing to the internal thing. When I've previously asked, on MO, how to define the "standard model of arithmetic", some answers suggested there was more too it (not necessarily first order expressible).  So you can forgive my confusion here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Claim:  $T+$"$T$ is $\omega$-complete" is inconsistent. For suppose it's consistent and now work in a model $V$ of this theory. Let $T^+$ be the resulting completion of $T$ (i.e. the unique theory of the $\omega$-models of $T$ in the sense of $V$). Then note that $T^+$ is a $\Delta^1_1$ real, so $T^+\in L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}}$. But $L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}}\subseteq\mathrm{wfp}(M)$ whenever $M\models T$ is an $\omega$-model, and therefore every real $x\in L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}}$ is such that $x\leq_{\mathrm{T}} T^+$ (the sub-$\mathrm{T}$ there being "Turing", as opposed to the theory $T$). (Given $x$, fix a wellorder $W$ of $\omega$ in ordertype $\alpha$ with $x\in L_\alpha$. Then (roughly) $T^+$ models "$W$ is a wellorder", and can recover $x$ from $W$. (Edited in:) Formally, fix an integer $e$ which indexes a recursive wellorder of $\omega$ in ordertype $\alpha$ with $x\in L_\alpha$. Recall $L_\alpha$ projects to $\omega$, and $x\leq_{\mathrm{T}} t^{L_\alpha}$, the first-order theory of $L_\alpha$. Fix a Turing reduction $n$ of $x$ from $t^{L_\alpha}$. Then for $m<\omega$, we have $m\in x$ iff $T^+$ contains the statement "Let $\beta$ be the ordertype of the wellorder coded by $e$, and let $y\leq_{\mathrm{T}} t^{L_\beta}$ via the $n$th Turing program; then $m\in y$".) But with $T^+\in L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}}$, this gives a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice! However, I think your proof that $x\le_TT^+$ isn't complete. Specifically, we **cannot** computably build $L_\alpha$ from a copy of $\alpha$, so "[we] can recover $x$ from $W$" isn't really correct on the nose. (In fact, given a well-ordering $A$, the only reals computable from all copies of $A$ are the computable ones.) I think I see how to get around this though.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it also doesn't really make sense to say $T^+$ models "$W$ is a wellorder''; it should be that we let $e$ be some integer which is the index of a wellorder of $\omega$ of the right length in whatever coding we're using, and from that integer, $T^+$ recovers $x$. (That's more formally what I had in mind.)

Comment: I think the following works: grab a whole model instead of just the theory. Specifically, working within $V\models S$, the $L$-least real $r$ coding an $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$ is hyperarithmetic and hence its jump is an element of the structure it codes, which it consequently computes - an obvious absurdity.

Comment: (I'm not saying to computably build (the theory of) $L_\alpha$ from the wellorder, but that for each $x$, there are integers $e,n$ such that $m\in x$ iff $T^+$ contains the statement "Let $\alpha$ be the ordertype of the wellorder given by $e$, and $y$ be the $n$th real of the theory of $L_\alpha$; then $m\in y$".)

Comment: Ah, I see. I find it a bit easier to think in terms of coding structures, but you're right, that works; if you modify the answer to include this, I'll accept it!

Comment: Okay, I added it in.

Comment: Is this answer enough to conclude that there is a specific sentence $\varphi$ such that $T$ proves 'if there are $\omega$-models of $T$, then there are $\omega$-models of $T + \varphi$ and $T+\neg \varphi$?